# Remove faucet valve stem

Tags: leak, faucet

How do I remove this faucet valve stem. The white part doesn't have enough hight to unscrew. The metal part right under it doesn't unscrew when using a socket wrench. How do I remove this valve stem?

[image]
[image]

[image]
**I put WD-40 on the base the night before and again before trying to unscrew. It doesn't work. Socket only strips the metal. How do I remove this valve stem? Size is 15/16 inches.** 
[image]

Comment: I believe the chrome piece with the hex nut shape on top can be unscrewed, otherwise why would it have the hex nut built into it.  Use a wrench on the chrome hex on top of the fitting and slowly try and loosen.  Use WD40 to help loosen the thread.

Comment: @Programmer66 A wrentch doesn't unscrew it. The wrench just pops up. They would have gave more height if it was suppose to be screwable.

Comment: You already took the handle off. That's the valve stem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to need a socket similar to this one (but in the size you need):

[Stem Socket](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Armour-Line-29-32-in-and-31-32-in-Shower-Valve-Socket-for-Removing-Tub-and-Shower-Stems-RP77312/306699612)

Comment: That didn't work at all. It just strips. How do I get it off? See image. I used WD-40 first.

Comment: It may be seized so badly that it cannot be disassembled.  You may have to replace the entire faucet.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need a thin wall socket to fit over the white portion of the valve to remove it. You might be able to grab it with a pair of pliers straight down and twist counterclockwise. Measure the white nut flat side to flat side and check at your home store for a socket in the plumbing section, unless you have your own sockets.

Comment: I don't think there's enough space even with a very think socket. I uploaded another image.

Comment: They do make them that thin.... in the plumbing section of your home store or a plumbing supply store.

Comment: That didn't work at all. It just strips. How do I get it off? See image. I used WD-40 first.

Answer (score 1):

Apply WD40 to base of chrome before trying to loosen,  the calcium deposit probably corroded the threads. Apply Wd40 a couple of times and allow for penetration.  It has to be a wrench or better yet, a socket that fits the nut. Pliers will not work.   Push down on the socket as you try and loosen the chrome piece.  
[image]

Comment: Do you know what socket I can buy from lowes. It's 28/32. I uploaded another image. Preferably from Lowes.

Comment: I think it's 22mm or 23mm socket. I see them now. I'll get both and bring my socket to see if it fits.

Comment: From the picture on your wrench, it looks like 5/8",  I do not believe it would be a metric.

Comment: That didn't work at all. It just strips. How do I get it off? See image. I used WD-40 first. It was 15/16